# How to remove a tag from a commit in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Looks like there's no way to checkout a previous commit in Visual Studio 2019 except by adding tags and then checking out the commit with the tag. It works (sometimes), but it's clunky.

Is there a way to remove a tag from a commit after adding it? Using Windows and the built-in Git functionality in Visual Studio 2019. I don't have any other Git utilities installed in Windows.

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a way to remove a tag from a commit after adding it? (...) Visual Studio (...).

In `Visual Studio 2022`'s search textbox, type in "terminal" and hit enter:

[image]

"Developer Powershell" opens, in which you can use `git tag -d v2.0.1` for example and hit enter again:

[image]

Open or refresh the git history tab to see that the tag has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout a previous commit by doing a hard or soft reset on your local branch with VS2019. That will reset your local branch back to a specific commit and (locally) drop or keep, respectively, the changes made since that commit.

I think MS purposefully made it hard to remove a commit tag. If you're using Azure Dev-ops, you can try the [Tags area in their portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-tags?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) .

Otherwise, I'm seeing nothing allowing you to manage this in VS2019. You can [install Git](https://git-scm.com/) and use a command like [git tag -d <tag_name>](https://devconnected.com/how-to-delete-local-and-remote-tags-on-git/) for a local tag.